# Check if stream can read so that it does not throw an exception c#

Tags: c#, stream

I am using TCP client

Here is my code

```
do
{

   responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

   bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

} while (bytes != 0);
```

I got the error here sometimes

```
bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
```

The exisiting connection is forcibly closed by the server.

How to handle it.

How to check if the stream can read on not.

On server side i am writing to the stream and closing it. Should i do something on server??

Comment: You can't. The server is acting independently from your client - so between *checking* that the stream is okay, and *reading* from it, the server could close the connection.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So you are saying that i need to use try catch to handle this pathetic??

Comment: It's what I'd recommend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code will work fine for a normal / healthy scenario, where the stream closes normally. What you describe ("the existing connection is forcibly closed by the server") is *not* the normal / healthy scenario, so it is entirely reasonable that it tells you about this problem, which it does by throwing an exception. The same as you might expect if you are reading from a file, and the file-system becomes unavailable (somebody yanks a disk / pen-drive, etc).

So: `catch` the exception and handle it appropriately.

There isn't anything special you can do on the server except close the stream *nicely*.